# Can't restart animation with css add/remove inside setInterval function

Tags: javascript

I have problem that I can use this to restart animation
in global scope, in onclick() event functions

```
document.getElementById('weapon').classList.remove('animation1');
document.getElementById("weapon").classList.add('animation1');
```

but it doesn't work inside setInerval() function, anywhere I put this into code.
Example code:

```js
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar"); 
  var max_health = 100;
  var current_health = 100;  
  var width = 100;
  elem.innerHTML = current_health + '/' + max_health;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 500);
    elem.style.transition = 'width 2s';
  function frame() {
    if (width <= 0) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {  
        var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
        var dmg_done = number;
        current_health = current_health - dmg_done;
        width = width - number; 
        elem.innerHTML = current_health + '/' + max_health;
      
        
        if (current_health <= 0){
            elem.innerHTML = 0 + '/' + max_health;
        }
        if(number >= width) {
            elem.style.width = 0 + '%';    
        }
            elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
    
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post your html code too

Comment: My god atm it is meshed up, won't paste it all, but there is nothing special, but I made it more simple -  bar used from w3 example, one image and  one animation, there is css added too https://pastebin.com/7gXjhrWA

Comment: you can share a link from jsfiidle or codepen for example. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358212/how-do-i-include-code-for-jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0uvL59qh/7/ made for you, bar has little problem on second click coz it resets but w/e, here made square and animation for this. Outside setinterval it works, it adding it; I can remove, add, remove, add and it works outside function move/frame.

Comment: It works in my side. What's not working for you?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kwyoa86n/1/ becouse I made one animation outside to show it works outside, look now.

Comment: Can I refresh this thread?

Comment: what do you mean by refresh?

Comment: To make this topic again on top if stackoverflow works like typical forum. Haven't recive solution of alternative way of my idea yet. @Addis